# Storing integers in c-implemented hash tables?

Tags: c, hashtable

Currently I have a hash table implementation in C that uses strings as the keys and values. If I wanted to store integers instead of strings as the values, what would be the best way to do this? I'm thinking of storing the integer in a string and converting it to an integer when I need it but it seems inefficient for arithmetic. Something like

```
insert("money", "13");
int i = atoi(get("key1"));
int sum = i + 10;
insert("money", itoa(sum));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: hash table implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tableentry /* hashtab entry */
{
    struct tableentry *next;
    char *key;
    char *val;
} tableentry_t;

typedef struct hashtable
{
    size_t size;
    struct tableentry **tab;
} hashtable_t;

/* creates hashtable */
/* NOTE: dynamically allocated, remember to ht_free() */
hashtable_t *ht_create(size_t size)
{
    hashtable_t *ht = NULL;
    if ((ht = malloc(sizeof(hashtable_t))) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* allocate ht's table */
    if ((ht->tab = malloc(sizeof(tableentry_t) * size)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* null-initialize table */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ht->tab[i] = NULL;
    ht->size = size;
    return ht;
}

/* creates hash for a hashtab */
static unsigned hash(hashtable_t *ht, char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval;
}

/* loops through linked list freeing */
static void te_free(tableentry_t *te)
{
    tableentry_t *next;
    while (te != NULL)
    {
        next = te->next;
        free(te->key);
        free(te->val);
        free(te);
        te = next;
    }
}

/* creates a key-val pair */
static tableentry_t *new(char *k, char *v)
{
    tableentry_t *te = NULL;

    if ((te = calloc(1, sizeof(*te))) == NULL
        || (te->key = strdup(k)) == NULL
        || (te->val = strdup(v)) == NULL)
    {
        te_free(te);
        return NULL;
    }
    te->next = NULL;
    return te;
}

static tableentry_t *lookup(hashtable_t *ht, char *k)
{
    tableentry_t *te;
    /* step through linked list */
    for (te = ht->tab[hash(ht, k) % ht->size]; te != NULL; te = te->next)
        if (strcmp(te->key, k) == 0)
            return te; /* found */
    return NULL; /* not found */
}

/* inserts the key-val pair */
hashtable_t *ht_insert(hashtable_t *ht, char *k, char *v)
{
    tableentry_t *te;
    /* unique entry */
    if ((te = lookup(ht, k)) == NULL)
    {
        te = new(k, v);
        unsigned hashval = hash(ht, k) % ht->size;
        /* insert at beginning of linked list */
        te->next = ht->tab[hashval]; 
        ht->tab[hashval] = te;
    }
    /* replace val of previous entry */
    else
    {
        free(te->val);
        if ((te->val = strdup(v)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
    return ht;
}

/* retrieve value from key */
char *ht_get(hashtable_t *ht, char *k)
{
    tableentry_t *te;
    if ((te = lookup(ht, k)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return te->val;
}

/* frees hashtable created from ht_create() */
void ht_free(hashtable_t *ht)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++)
        if (ht->tab[i] != NULL)
            te_free(ht->tab[i]);
    free(ht);
}

/* resizes hashtable, returns new hashtable and frees old*/
hashtable_t *ht_resize(hashtable_t *oht, size_t size)
{
    hashtable_t *nht; /* new hashtable */
    nht = ht_create(size);
    /* rehash */
    int i;
    tableentry_t *te;
    /* loop through hashtable */
    for (i = 0; i < oht->size; i++)
        /* loop through linked list */
        for (te = oht->tab[i]; te != NULL; te = te->next)
            if (ht_insert(nht, te->key, te->val) == NULL)
                return NULL;
    ht_free(oht);
    return nht;
}
```

Comment: is just using C++ an option? :|

Comment: I'm confused why you can't just change the key type to integer, and hash on the integer key.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I want to hash with a string (using char pointer as the key) and store an integer (integer is the value). My hash table implementation uses string for both though.

Comment: "My hash table implementation uses string" --> post that code else this is too broad.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow.  Are you asking how to use your existing hash table implementation, unmodified, to store integer values, or are you asking how your implementation can be modified to handle integer values?  Or are you open to both?

Comment: I want to know how I can use the existing hash table implementation, unmodified, to store integer values.

Comment: If it has to be "unmodified", then you can do what you're doing now, convert numbers to strings. It will be inefficient, and consume more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access and manipulation functions associated with your hash table implementation assume that values have the form of null-terminated strings, and that their significance is carried entirely by their contents (not, for example, by the values of the pointers themselves).  Among other things, this is evident from the fact that the `new()` and `ht_insert()` functions make copies of the provided values via `strdup()`.  Therefore, if you intend to use those functions (not just the underlying data structures) then your only alternative for storing integers is to encode the integers into strings in some way, and store the strings.  This is what you already came up with.

Note, by the way, that this presents a bit of an issue if you want to be able to store both strings and integers in the same hash table.  The table entries do not provide any way to record data type metadata, so to avoid collisions between string and number representations, you would need to encode data types into the values you store -- not only for the integers, but for the strings, too.  For example, you might encode values into strings whose first character communicates the data type.  Thus, perhaps `"S12345"` represents the *string* `"12345"`, whereas `"I12345"` represents the *integer* `12345`.  But you don't need such tricks if you assume all the values are of uniform type, on a table-by-table basis.

You would have more options if you were open to writing at least a partial set of alternative hash table functions for storing integers in the existing data structures.  For example, you might use the fact that pointers and integers can be converted back and forth (with implementation-defined results). But I interpret you to have rejected such approaches, as using alternative functions is effectively the same thing as modifying the implementation.

Comment: Ok, maybe it would be worth it to modify the implementation file. What is the most effective way of doing that?

Comment: It depends, @DavidTran, on what modifications you're willing to make, and on what features you want to support.  If you want to support data values of varying type, with type-specific handling, through a generic API, then your entries need to bear an additional member by which the value's type is recorded.  In that case, I might also specify the value type as a union, maybe something like `union { char *as_string; int as_int; /* ... */ } val;`.  One would then choose which member of the union to access based on the type metadata carried by the entry.

Comment: I was wondering whether to use that (unions) or to store the value in the struct as a `void *`, adding a struct member to `hashtable_t` to keep track of it's type, and acting accordingly with the other functions. Would this work as well?

Comment: That's two different questions.  First, yes, if each hash table is to carry values of consistent type, then you can put the metadata conveying that data type into the overall hash table type, once, instead of into each entry.  Second, yes, you can use a `void *`, +/- actual dynamic allocation in various cases, to store the values.  Do note that approaches that require dynamic memory allocation are much more costly than those that don't.